# Javascript functions to dynamically generate html elements

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a file that has Javascript functions, an html file. I am trying to run node js and call the Javascript functions within the html file to dynamically create sentences, paragraphs, buttons, etc.
I have written some code and can't figure out why it is not working. Here's an example of trying to create a sentence:

**Javascript file**

```
function createSentence (Sentence) {
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(Sentence);
para.appendChild(node);
return para;
}
```

**Html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></script><script type='text/javascript' src='https://3fff7b133eda5c4b3ff4e8218aa7df3f97359aad.googledrive.com/host/0BzXiziikGpV9flRzQkY5VUdkY0g1WjM2aFBrX3U5WmZUU0h2MFVfcnZJNnBhdWowQWVmbVU/createHit.js'></script></head><body>
<div id = "radio_home"></div>
<script language='Javascript'>
document.getElementById("radio_home").appendChild(createSentence(Sentence));
</script></body></html>
```

The "src" within the html file contains the path to the Javascript file which is hosted publicly on Google drive. I am expecting it to display the Sentence in the spot where it says "radio_home" within the div when the html page renders, but that is not what I am seeing.
Would someone please check the code and help me with the syntax?

Comment: what is the value of the variable `Sentence`

Comment: That code will throw a reference error (for `Sentence` used from the main html). And the JavaScript file is currently invalid (as it is missing a brace). Please read the error console.

Comment: closing } at least is missing

Comment: Is the `language` attribute on that script tag even valid?  I've never seen that used elsewhere.

Comment: My apologies, the Javascript file missing a brace is a typo when I copied the code over. In which of the files and how should I declare Sentence?

Comment: You need to put a `}` at the end of the Javascript file. Also, `document.getElementById("radio_home").appendChild(createSentence(Sentence));`, what is the value of `Sentence`? You need to pass a `String` to the function as an argument. You should try something like: `document.getElementById("radio_home").appendChild(createSentence("This is a sentence."));`. You should remove the `language` attribute as well.

Comment: You should remove the *language* attribute, it was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML 5.

Comment: Thank you. I tried removing the language attribute as you suggested but it then throws an error ("There was an error parsing the HTML5 data in your request.  Please make sure the data is well-formed and validates as HTML5. Details: Errors: <! [4,181] Saw “=” when expecting an attribute name."). Does the syntax need to change somehow after removing the language attribute? If so, how?

Comment: `<head></script>` is invalid HTML, as there is no open `<script>` element; however a browser won't "error" on it; it'll handle it in some fashion. Also the reported "error" has naught to do with removing `language='JavaScript'` (properly).

Answer (score 0):

As Abraar Arique stated. Replace `Sentense` with your text, like "This is my text.":

```
document.getElementById("radio_home").appendChild(createSentence("This is my text."));
```

Also `language='Javascript'` is not valid. Rather use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```